# Making Configuration thread safe using locking in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, thread-safety, locking

I have a configuration bean which stores some default values which are read from a .properties file. The values are then updated based on a REST request, and these can be refreshed at any time.

I have a multi-thread application, so in theory the values of this configuration bean may be *read* many times per second, while the values will only need to be *written to* on a very infrequent basis.

Currently the 'read' is just using a conventional `@Getter` but I could write a method to access the values of this bean if required.

How best should I make this thread-safe? I've read about re-entrant locking, and synchronized methods, but these (particularly the latter) seem like overkill here?

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "configuration.default.values")
public class ConfigurationBean {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Map<String, String> configValues;

    @PostConstruct
    private void updateConfigValuesRealTime(){
        // initially carry out REST request to update default config values to real ones
        refreshValuesFromRESTCall();
    }

    public void refreshValuesFromRESTCall(){
       // Publicly accessibly method to carry out a REST call to refresh the values of the config bean. 
        this.configValues = client.downstreamCall();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make the field `volatile`. This still means calls to the getter will be slower but trying to twist yourself into knots setting up grievously complicated schemes to try to dance around it has one seriously nasty problem:

JMM violations (Java Memory Model, the spec that explains what guarantees the JVM provides about concurrent access to fields) are **impossible** to test.

So, you might have something that seems to work every time and then 2 years from now you redeploy your stuff on, say, an ARM chip based IAAS deployment and all of a sudden once every blue moon weird stuff happens. You're literally signing yourself up for a *month* of bugtracking down the line. Don't get fancy with JMM issues unless you truly must, based on actual observed performance issues *and* a profiler report indicating that indeed the problem is the fact that you have a contention-controlled lookup someplace.

Thus, my advice: Mark that field `volatile`.

### But.. take a broader view

Threading just isn't that simple. The major problem is that you can no longer think in lego bricks. Take, as a trivial example, this code:

```
Map<Integer, String> numberNames = ....;
if (!numberNames.containsKey(5)) {
  numberNames.put(5, callTranslationService("five"));
}
```

Has a problem: **You cannot make it thread safe the way you are doing it** - you want the above operation to be on its own atomic, and because it calls 2 separate methods on the map, it cannot be made atomic by simply ensuring each individual method is 'safe'.

Without theading, you can think in lego bricks: We have the `containsKey` brick and the `put` brick and we click them together to make this feature. But when threading is involved you can no longer think that way. Instead you have to consider the whole operation as a single concept. Hence, it is **not possible** to make the above code threadsafe at the lego brick level. Instead you have to reimagine the API and ensure this thing is a single lego brick, which is actually what the Map interface has done since.. java 8, I think:

```
numberNames.computeIfAbsent(5, k -> callTranslationService("five"));
```

- this doesn't mean `computeIfAbsent` is threadsafe on a `HashMap` (it is not!!), but that, given that it is a single lego brick, it is now conceivable to write an implementation of the map interface that *could be* threadsafe even if the callers don't do any locking. And, indeed, `j.u.c.ConcurrentMap` *is* threadsafe when you write it with `computeIfAbsent` and is not when you use `containsKey` + `put`.

The other alternative is that the caller does it, e.g:

```
synchronized (someLock) {
  if (!map.containsKey(5)) {
    map.put(5, callTranslationService("five"));
  }
}
```

can also be fine.

The point is, if locking is relevant, it is extremely likely 'just figure out how to ensure each individual method in my API is threadsafe' is **not** a suitable answer. It is possible that your configuration object can 'get away with it' (which effectively means: Every operation you can do with this API is always just one lego brick, it is never a sequence of calls which need to give consistent results), but I doubt it: Imagine some code needs **2** config properties to make a decision about what to do: Now 'just make all fields `volatile` and call it a day' is no longer suitable. Because that does not, and cannot be adapted to, provide a consistent answer. After all, if you did that, the following could happen:

- Property A is currently 1, and property B is currently 2.
- Thread X Reads property A. Value read is 1.
- Thread Y triggers a full config reload
- this overwrites both A and B; they are currently 10 and 20.
- Thread X reads property B. Value read is 20.

Thread X now has values 1 and 20. However, this is inconsistent: No config file has ever existed with A/B having values 1/20. There's only the world where it was 1/2, and the world where it was 10/20.

Thus, we get to the final answer:

### The in depth answer

- It is likely you need to thoroughly reconsider all of this, and the locking mechanism (or other 'consistency' concept you want to introduce here) needs to be done at a completely different level. This part also involves writing documentation explaining the specifics, and how you intend for callers to use your config object so they get consistent answers.
- ... but in the somewhat unlikely case you conclude there is no need for that, or you document explicitly that no consistency guarantees are possible and thus you let the callers figure it out... just mark the fields as `volatile`, easy fix.